# How to retrieve data from firebase database in a efficient way

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android app in which I have to compare a node and retrieve some values if node is exist and store these values in *`SharedPreferences`* as shown in code:

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
dbRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        //Toast.makeText(google_sign_in.this, "In sign in firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
            editor.putString("phone", ds.child("phone").getValue(String.class));
            editor.putString("email", ds.child("email").getValue(String.class));
            editor.putString("fullName", ds.child("fName").getValue(String.class));
            editor.putString("lastName", ds.child("lName").getValue(String.class));
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

**OnCreate method**

```
sf = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
name = sf.getString("firstName", "null") + " " + sf.getString("lastName", "null");
```

**Problem**

name is always `null` whenever activity launched for the first time.
When the activity launch for the first time ,data retrieving process is too slow and i received null value from `sharedpreference`even I put this block of code in `OnStart` method.

**What i want**

I want to retrieve all data before launching of this activity so that I don't receive `null` value from `sharedpreferences`.

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, so your `sf.getString("lastName", "null")` likely runs before the `editor.putString("lastName", ds.child("lName").getValue(String.class))` is called. If you run the code in a debugger, or add some logging you can verify this. For this reason any code that needs the data needs to be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Answer (score 0):

According to Android lifecycle, `onCreate` is executed before `onStart`. Paste the code in `onCreate`.

Source: [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: ok fine I pased the code in OnCreate method but didn't get what i wont. I want to retrieve all these data before launching the activity

Comment: Do you have a splash screen activity... If you have, paste the code there. If not create a span screen activity.. u can display splash screen saying loading

Comment: yes I have splash screen activity and also I agree with your suggestion, let's try it.

Comment: can you tell me where i paste this block of code in splash screen . Either in OnCreate or in Handler

Comment: use pastebin or github or protectedtext

Comment: forbidden...cant see. u set it as private

Comment: sorry I can't use this code in splash screen. If you have another solution please give me. Thanks for suggestion and willing to help me.

Comment: Share the full code of the activity where u use these codes! Just edit the previous post.